# Play framework thread IDs

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework, akka

We have a Play! app which uses akka actors to enable concurrent & throttled communication with an external service.

It's been working mostly fine except for some OOM exceptions every couple of days.

Today I added the thread to the logger and noticed something I want to make sure I understand.

I see the worker thread names are ever increasing and I'm assuming it means they are created on the thread pool.

Here's an excerpt from our logs:

> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-231 [ ]: /
> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-489 [ ]:
> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-89 [ ]:
> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-403 [ ]:
> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-317 [ ]:
> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-175 [ ]:
> - Aug 16 20:59:45 XXX.com production: INFO  ForkJoinPool-6-worker-459 [ ]:

I checked using

> ps huH p

and there are no more thread than expected.

What I'm worried about the most is we are keeping some zombie objects clogging the system.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Grab a heap dump when it runs out of memory. Chances are you have one object which will consume much of the memory.

Comment: Do you have calls to 'blocking' (eg. Await.result)? In combination with the default execution context, the pool size may be dynamically adjusted/increased.

Comment: John, thank you, I will.
@rethab - I do have some blocking calls, but they are all on a different threadpool (AFAIK). The main issue is that those numbers keep on getting larger - i.e. in the beginning it is worker-50 and after some work being done it reaches 'worker-489' and rises even further.